# What is the closed form of $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2i}{2^i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I looked at $\frac{\sum 2i}{\sum2^i}$ (division), however both expressions are not equal. I am looking for an expression like $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2i}{2^i}=5n$ for example.

Comment: Look up arithmetico–geometric sequence (e.g. on wiki).

Comment: [Gosper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm) gives $$4-2^{1-n} (n+2)$$

Comment: @Milten Is the answer 6? I have put it in the formula in the link you provided but I am not sure

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try to compare your expression with $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ where $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x+x^{2}+...+x^{n}\right)$

Comment: What a cool trick

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want solution for the second expression, I misunderstood you question.
So for that you can write this as a value of a serie or troncated series

$$ f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty \   \text{OR} \ N}a_ix^i$$

That you know the explicit expression.

You know that after derivation and variable change

$$ f'(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty \   \text{OR} \ N}a_{i+1}(i+1)x^i $$

Remark that you can continue the process for higher order.

For your problem, take a particular value of $f'(x)$ (here is 1/2).